# How to check how many Divisors there's in a whole number and How to express a factorial equation to Odd numbers?

Tags: java

So my homework tells me to write the equation for a ODD number, the equation must be a factorial if and only if the number is odd.

In my head I the structured came like this (until I don't know how to use the factorial)

```
import java.util.*;

  public class apple {
public static void main(String args []) {
    Scanner var = new Scanner(System.in);
    int m;
    System.out.println("Type in your first number: ");
    m = var.nextInt();
    if (m==0){ //i don't know if m==0 express the condition to be whole numbers, please tell me which is.
        //here I need to check how many divisors there is for my statement
    }else if //Again, i don't know how to proceed here, i need to place the condition if M is ODD, how?
        //here i need to state (what i guess) the equation of factorial number (in which case, if and only if is odd)

    // and than print the results out. That is all the job it needs to be done.
    }
}
 }
```

Comment: what do you mean with "the equation for an ODD number" Jay?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it seems like you want to print out the factorial of a number if you have an odd number and the divisors of the number if it is even. You haven't specified a way to present the divisors, so here's one way you could do it:

```
Scanner var = new Scanner(System.in);
int m;
long x=1; //for the factorial, we want to store in a long to combat data overflow
System.out.println("Type in your first number: ");
m = var.nextInt();
//if the input is odd we calculate its factorial
if (m%2==1){
    for (int i = 1;i<=m;i++)
        x*=i;
    System.out.println(m+"!: "+x);
}
else{
    System.out.println("1 is a divisor for "+m);
    System.out.println("2 is a divisor for "+m);
    if (m%3==0)
        System.out.println("3 is a divisor for "+m);
    //and so on for more divisors of m
}
```

Comment: There are obviously more ways to organize the divisors and present them to the user, but that is up to you.

Comment: Indeed! I was confused on how to organize the "for" and how should it be the organizers, you captured what I was trying to say. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

A first note, you need to add "throws IOException" after your close parentheses in the main declaration since you are asking the computer for input.

How to detect if a number is odd. x=number.
if(x%2==1)
    //Then the number is odd
else
    //The number is even

How to detect if the number is a whole number: whole meaning an integer greater than 0. You already know its an integer (Thats what you are asking for with nextInt().) so all you need to say is:
if(m>0)
    //Then it is whole

Please clarify on anything this did not answer, your question was a bit vague.

Comment: Ok, so indeed i made a mess with the "whole number" thing, what i meant to say was; If the number is EVEN than the procedure is to get the divisors from that number, and print it out for the user the results.

Comment: So now, as for the odd number goes, it would be something like "if (m%2==1)" to represent that the input number was odd? and with that result, how could I write the code to show in a factorial equation?